# Getting the correct Sharepoint 2010 CMIS atompub

Tags: 2010, cmis

I am a Sharepoint beginner and am try to connect to an installation via CMIS (using AtomPub) and can't get it to connect. I can connect from Sharepoint itself (using the CMIS Producer and Consumer, and get a list of repositories).

My question is how do I determine what the correct atompubutl is ?

It appears to want it in the following format ...

```
http://<host>/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/<SPList>?getrepositoryinfo
```

I know what the  should be, but what does the  represent ? What part of the location in Sharepoint does this represent, and how to I know what to configure it to ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I've sorted this out - now moved on to other Sharepoint/CMIS issues!

Correct URL is `http://<hostname>/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/<repository-id>?getRepositoryInfo`

To summarize ...

> "Try using `http://<hostname>/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/<repository-id>/getRepositoryInfo`, where  is the ID for the SP list or document library you're trying to access. I've found the easiest way to get this ID is in SharePoint Designer -- open the site in SPD, navigate to "Lists and Libraries", and select the one you're trying to access. The resulting page will contain a value for "List ID" that looks like {xxx}. Just use the xxx for the in your URL, not the curly braces. (The actual ID will be much longer than just xxx.)"
>
> ...
>
> `http://<hostname>/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/<repository-id>/getRepositoryInfo` should be:
>
> `http://<hostname>/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/<repository-id>?getRepositoryInfo`

(taken from [MSDN Question/Answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/6553d9d7-1eac-4b6b-aec7-12ebed9b0b0e))